# Testing EJB Remote Interfaces with JNDI

Tags: jakarta-ee, jndi

I am trying to follow an example program that was written to test the remote interfaces for EJB's. Inside of the test class they have declared:

```
    private static final String contestJNDI = System.getProperty("jndi.name.contest",
        "companyEAR/companyEJB/ContestEJB!com.company.interfaces.ContestRemote");
```

Where do the following 2 references need to be defined? A web.xml file?

```
"jndi.name.contest"
```

and

```
"companyEAR/companyEJB/ContestEJB!com.company.interfaces.ContestRemote"
```

Answer (score 0):

It is likely JNDI mappings are defined in an application-server-specific configuration file (the deployment descriptor) like a `jboss.xml` for example inside the ear file.

Comment: I am using a Jboss server, but there is no jboss.xml file declared in the WAR. I do have a web.xml file that has a context-param declaration. The param-value matches the 2nd argument in the getProperty() call, but the param-name is contest-remote.